# Mule can't convert json response to object

Tags: json, rest, mule

I can't convert JSON response from REST WS to object by JSON-to-Object component in Mule (3.8 CE runtime). Returned class in component java.util.HashMap (I also tried ArrayList)
JSON response

```
[{
        "userId": 123456,
        "otherId": 654321
    }, {
        "userId": 123457,
        "otherId": 654321
    }, {
        "userId": 123458,
        "otherId": 654321
    }
]
```

I received error

```
ERROR 2019-02-12 11:37:32,386 [[demorestmapper].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to transform from "json" to "java.util.HashMap"
Payload               : org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@77054f71
Transformer           : JsonToObject{this=2c88a3e8, name='JsonToHashMap', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.util.HashMap, mimeType='application/json', encoding='null'}, sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=java.io.Reader, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.net.URL, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.File, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=[B, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}]}
Element               : /demorestmapperFlow/processors/3 @ demorestmapper:demorestmapper.xml:18 (JSON to Object)
Element XML           : <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"></json:json-to-object-transformer>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashMap out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@563690a7; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because it is a JSON Array. SO you need to specify in the transformer to convert it to an array of maps/objects:

For array:

```
 <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap[]" />`
```

vs map:

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />`
```

Comment: It's working. Could tell me how I can get only "userId" fro this Json. I already have hashmap and I want to use only "userId" in for each component as a collection

Comment: In Mel in the for each you can just use #[payload.userid]

Comment: Finally, I got it. In "collection" attribute in for each component I use #[payload]. Inside loop i use #[payload.userId]